# cakephp Acl Component and Inheritance

Tags: cakephp, components, cakephp-1.3, acl

cakephp acl component make roles like this:

- admin

- add_post
- delete_post
- edit_post
- view_post
- add_link
- delete_link
- edit_link
- view_link
- add_page
- delete_page
- edit_page
- view_page

manager_1:

- add_post
- view_post

manager_2:

- add_link
- view_link

manager_3:

- add_page
- view_page

users:

view_post

now i will add a user to manager_1 and manager_2.

how i can do this with cakephp acl component???

maybe in this example i can create 4 or 5 different group. but when this options are many, i have to make group's role inheritance.

can i do this in cakephp acl component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to tell the ACL component to which ARO Group your User belongs. You can do that by implementing the parentNode() method in your User model. You can find an example of it [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1321/Using-the-AclBehavior).